Integrate VSCode in a xaml/C# application
I was wondering if it is possible to use VSCode as a component in xaml/C# application, like a powerful customizable rich text editor that manages large text files. I was using Actipro Syntax Editor in another app, but I am looking for other possibilities. BR,
Tried to determine on the net, but I only found how to use VSCode for xxxx, never how to embed VSCode in an application.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
